# redirect incoming traffic from certain referrers

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to find an htaccess or PHP code that does the following. I'll just type this out as pseudo-code:

IF (incoming traffic sources) = referrer.com, refer1.com, anotherrefer3.com and site4.com,
REDIRECT_GOTO_THIS_PAGE => http://www.mysite.com/specific-landing-page-for-those-people

I'm finding a lot of htaccess rewrites that are close to this, but so far none that do this specific thing. I'm hoping to find something that takes care of a whole pile of referrer/incoming url's in one shot; thanks.

UPDATE:

This one looks promising:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?partnerwebsite\.com
 RewriteRule ^$ /other_directory/specific_page.shtml [L]
```

How would I add several url's there on line 2?

Whew. Htaccess. Woah.

Comment: You mean all requests from those web sites will be written to `/other_directory/specific_page.shtml`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly then I would do it in php as follows:

```
  $refs = array("http://referer1.com","http://referer2.com");
  if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$refs)) {
      header("location: http://redirected_here.com");
  }
```

Comment: sorry, one bracket was missing. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that worked like a charm for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*xxx.org.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*yyy.org.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*zzz.com.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*aaa.net.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your_site/different_page/
```

Add it to your .htaccess file. If you don't have a .htaccess file (typically for index pages loaded from different directories), simply create a blank one and add the above.